# Why modulus operation work different in ruby than other languages?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, I get:

```
-5 % 3 # => 1
```

whereas other languages like PHP, Javascript, C++, and Java all produce the result `-2`. I don't understand this concept. I hope someone can explain this ruby's calculation method. It would be better if you could use an example of how it works.

Comment: You want `-5.remainder(3)` which returns `-2`

Comment: AFAIK `-5 % 3` is implementation defined in C and C++, that can be either `-2` or `1` depending on how the CPU implements modulus with negatives and what it thinks "smallest" means: `-2` is smaller than `1` because `-2 < 1` but `-2` is bigger than `1` because `|-2| > |1|`.

Comment: It is a matter of what you want as the set of representatives of the elements derived by modulo. It is whether you think `{-2, -1, 0}` more natural or `{0, 1, 2}` more natural. Ruby takes the latter, and so do I.

Answer (score 2):

It's in the docs: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Numeric.html#method-i-divmod

> If `q, r = x.divmod(y)`, then
>
> ```
> q = floor(x/y)
> x = q*y + r
> ```
>
> The quotient is rounded toward negative infinity

So `q` is -3 (-5 / 2 and round down, as per usual integer division rules). And `r = x - q * y = -5 - -3 * 2 = 1`